# How do I limit users to "liking" a post only once in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Basically I have a page that lists 10 most recent microposts. Each post has a like button. When this like button is clicked the likes table in my database is updated.

**Likes table:**

```
+----+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| id | likable_id | likable_type | created_at              | updated_at              | user_id |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
| 2  | 5770       | Micropost    | 2012-06-09 11:30:55 UTC | 2012-06-09 11:30:55 UTC | 2       |
| 3  | 5770       | Micropost    | 2012-06-09 11:42:45 UTC | 2012-06-09 11:42:45 UTC | 2       |
+----+------------+--------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
```

A user must only be able to like a micropost once. I can make this possible with some jquery/js by displaying an unlike button that points to a destroy path when ever a micropost is liked.

But is there a way to do this server side too? Like not allow a micropost to be liked more than once by any means necessary? So if I was to go into rails console and try to manually like a micropost I already liked it wouldn't work because it would see that I had already liked the micropost?

**Like model:**

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :likable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :likable_id, :likable_type, :user_id
end
```

**Micropost model:**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :likes, :as => :likable
end
```

**Likes controller:**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost])
     like = micropost.likes.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
     like.save
  end
end
```

**Likes form:**

```
<%= form_tag likes_path, :remote => true, :class => "like_micropost" do %>  
   <%= hidden_field_tag :micropost, micropost.id %>
       <%= submit_tag '', :class => "likeMicropostSubmit"  %> 
<% end %>
```

**I previous tried this with no luck:**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost])
    if micropost.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).nil?
     like = micropost.likes.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
     like.save
    end
  end
end
```

Kind regards

Comment: So, what's the question? In the `LikesController#create` search for existing like from that user and act accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# in Like class
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:likable_id, :likable_type]
```

This way you'll get validation error on trying to like something more than once.

[See docs for it.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about that validation rule. Been spending too much time on CSS/Jquery. Nice simple solution. Thanks

Comment: This technically still works, but the new validation syntax is often preferred in Rails 3+ apps:

`validates :uniqueness => true, :user_id, :scope => [:likable_id, :likable_type]`

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things:

1. Move the creation logic to the model (fat model, skinny controller)
2. Add a validation at the like creation (as jdoe already said)

So:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost])
    current_user.likes! micropost
  end
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:likable_id, :likable_type]
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # exclamation mark to avoid confusion between things that are liked by the user
  def likes!(likable_object)
    unless likable_object.likes.where(:user_id => self.id).exists?
      like = likable_object.likes.build(:user_id => self.id)
      like.save
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: Explanation:

1) Managing the Like creation phase is a model duty -> move the code that manages the creation to the model

2) Find a good method name for describe the action -> `User.likes! something` sounds good

3) Implement the creation method ->

```
def likes!(likable_object)
  like = likable_object.likes.build(:user_id => self.id)
  like.save
end
```

4) Add validation in order to manage the model valid/model invalid logic -> `class Like; validates_uniqueness_of ...`

5) Make the `likes!` method conscious of the valid/invalid logic ->

```
def likes!(likable_object)
  unless likable_object.likes.where(:user_id => self.id).exists?
    like = likable_object.likes.build(:user_id => self.id)
    like.save
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the benefit of `validates_uniqueness_of` if you still check 'likes' manually? Strange decision...

Comment: the benefit is that if you have a bug somewhere which causes the application to create a duplicate, the validation fails and your db remains coherent, that is: "Is a duplicated record valid?" "No" "Add a validation that invalides it"

Comment: With this skepticism you'll never be satisfied with any validation, won't you? :)

Comment: No, you are satisfied adding the needed validations :) The aim of validations is to make the model instance valid or invalid, so it is correct to use them in order to get that result (IMHO :-) )

Answer (score -1):

Ok this worked for me:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost])
    unless micropost.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).exists?
     like = micropost.likes.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
     like.save
    end
  end
end
```

Not having a create template is what was stopping it from working properly but the template is empty and un-used so wondering why it is mandatory.

Comment: It's not a controller's mission to be bothered by the data consistency!